# retrieving the workgroup name of a computer running windows operating system

Tags: java

I am currently working on my final year project at the University. I am developing a LAN messager program in JAVA. I would like to use the computer names as the usernames and the workgroups as the chatroom names. So far I don't have problems retrieving the computer names but the problem is with retrieving the workgroup names. Any assistance will be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you tried enumerating System.properties to see if it's in there?

Answer (score 0):

On my machine I have a System property `env.USERDNSDOMAIN` which holds my DNS domain.

I also have a System property `env.USERDOMAIN` which seems to hold my Windows domain name.

Answer (score 0):

After some googling, I found out you can access the Windows registry by using java.util.prefs.Preferences. Finding out where in the registry to look can be your homework :^)